# Set column width and row height to same values?

Tags: excel, vba

I set the column width to 14,5 and the row height to 14,5. Despite them being set to the same numbers, the column width is MUCH larger than the row height.

I don't know why this is, but I might have accidentally changed the unit of column with using VBA when I was working in another Excel file. How do I set the unit of measure back to standard? So that 14,5 is the same when looking at both column width and row height.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Source : **[Change the column width and row height](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/change-column-width-and-row-height-HP005198813.aspx)**

A `ColumnWidth` of 14.5 means you get 14.5 standard font characters in each line of each cell of the column.

> *Standard font : The default text font for worksheets. The standard font determines the default font for the Normal cell style.*

A `RowHeight` of 14.5 means you get a row in which each cell is 14.5 points high (when manually adjusting, you'll see this one in the pop-up; Hint: it's not the pixels).

**Therefore,** it is normal that the same numbers don't always display the same sizes. You have to play around with them and avoid changing the standard font once you have good values.